# XML with namespace Validation with XSD throws exception

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have a xml file which is a response from Webservice.It has got various namespaces involved with it. When I try to validate it with appropriate XSD its throwing "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'SOAP-ENV:Envelope'." The namespace declaration for all the namespaces are declared in the response.
Following is my code

```
try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory xmlFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
            .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            SAXSource mainInputStream = new SAXSource(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(new File("FIXEDINCOME_v3_0.xsd"))));
            SAXSource importInputStream1 =new SAXSource(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(new File("Rating.xsd"))));
            SAXSource importInputStream2 = new SAXSource(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(new File("Datatypes.xsd"))));
            Source[] sourceSchema = new SAXSource[]{mainInputStream , importInputStream1, importInputStream2};
            Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(sourceSchema);  
            xmlFact.setNamespaceAware(true);
            xmlFact.setSchema(schema);
            DocumentBuilder builder = xmlFact.newDocumentBuilder();
            xmlDOC = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(inputXML)));
            NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() {
                public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                    String uri;
                    if (prefix.equals("ns0"))
                        uri = "http://namespace.worldnet.ml.com/EDS/Standards/Common/Service_v1_0/";
                    else if (prefix.equals("ns1"))
                        uri = "http://namespace.worldnet.ml.com/EDS/Product/Services/Get_Product_Data_Svc_v3_0/";
                    else if (prefix.equals("ns2"))
                        uri = "http://namespace.worldnet.ml.com/DataSOA/Product/Objects/FixedIncome/FixedIncome_v3_0/";
                    else if (prefix.equals("ns3")) {
                        uri = "http://namespace.worldnet.ml.com/DataSOA/Product/Objects/Rating/Rating_v2_0/";
                    } else if (prefix.equals("SOAP-ENV")) {
                        uri = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap-envelope/";
                    } else
                        uri = null;

                    return uri;
                }

                // Dummy implementation - not used!
                public Iterator getPrefixes(String val) {
                    return null;
                }

                // Dummy implemenation - not used!
                public String getPrefix(String uri) {
                    return null;
                }
            };

            XPathFactory xpathFact = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            xPath = xpathFact.newXPath();
            xPath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: For these kind of issues, posting xml is a must

Comment: XML is way too big for me to post it. This is a generic issue actually. The XSD validator is not able to identify the namespace variables.

Comment: The question here is how will I let the DOM Parser know that the XML has got namespace.?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is with detecting the namespace definition for the SOAP-ENV prefix. The validator needs the XSD file that defines elements used in that namespace in order to validate the SOAP-ENV:Envelope element, so you need to tell the validator where that schema is located.

I think the solution is either to add the following to your XML reponse:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/      
           http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

Or, go download that schema off the web, save it to your local filesystem as an XSD file, and add it to your `sourceSchema` array. The first method should be preferred as it leads to more portable code (and XML).

Comment: it's a bad idea to run any production validation against schemas which are not available locally.  you don't want your production system to stop working because the remotely hosted resource is unavailable for some reason (not to mention the potential security issues).

Comment: It's also a bad idea to publish things on the web that don't reference a publicly available schema if they're meant to be validated. Like any engineering issue, there are good arguments for both sides and you have to consider the tradeoffs and make a decision appropriate for your application.

Comment: referencing the namespace certainly, but no, i don't agree that you need to reference a publicly available schema location.  that just encourages people to use it, which, as i already said, is a bad idea.  having the schema in a public location for people to download is certainly a good idea, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following URI for the SOAP-ENV?

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

Comment: Yes I have added that.<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap-envelope/"

Answer (score 0):

The set of schemas you are providing for validation does not include the soap schema.  you can either include the soap schema in the schema collection, or, if you don't care about validating the soap wrapper, just grab the actual body content element and run your validation from there.

Comment: Thanks for that one. Tried that too but its still throwing the same exception [Error] :1:57: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'FixedIncome'. FixedIncome is the parent element

Comment: @mavrav - actually, no, that's a different exception.  i gave 2 suggestions, which did you try?